# How to replace jquery function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with javascript/jquery and I struggle to make a quiz with jquery and javascript but I want to use only javascript and not jquery.

How can I use only javascript to let the quiz the same as now? Is there a way to skip the jquery?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-quiz-holder">
    <div id="intro-container" class="questionContainer">
        <a class="btnStart" href="#"><img src="img/start.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer hide">
        <div class="question">
            Vraag 1: Wat is de juiste spelling?
        </div>
        <ul class="answers">
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="a" type="radio" name="vraag1">Huisen</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="b" type="radio" name="vraag1">Huizen</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="c" type="radio" name="vraag1">Huiszen</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="d" type="radio" name="vraag1">Huize</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <div class="next">
                <a class="btnNext" href="#">Volgende</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer hide">
        <div class="question">
            Vraag 2: U bevindt zich momenteel:
        </div>
        <ul class="answers">
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="a" type="radio" name="vraag2">On line</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="b" type="radio" name="vraag2">On-line</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="c" type="radio" name="vraag2">Online</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <div class="prev">
                <a class="btnPrev" href="#">Vorige</a>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <a class="btnNext" href="#">Volgende</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer hide">
        <div class="question">
            Vraag 3: Een kleine sms?
        </div>
        <ul class="answers">
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="a" type="radio" name="vraag3">smsje</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="b" type="radio" name="vraag3">sms-je</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="c" type="radio" name="vraag3">sms'tje</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input data-key="d" type="radio" name="vraag3">sms'je</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <div class="prev">
                <a class="btnPrev" href="#">Vorige</a>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <a class="btnShowResult" href="#">Kijk na</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="results-container" class="questionContainer hide">
        <div id="resultKeeper">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressKeeper">
        <div id="progress">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="notice">
        Selecteer een optie
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    $(function(){
    var progress = $('#progress'),
            progressKeeper = $('#progressKeeper'),
            notice = $("#notice"),
            progressWidth = 548,
            answers= quiz.answers,
            userAnswers = [],
            questionLength= answers.length,
            questionsStatus = $("#questionNumber")
            questionsList = $(".question");

         function checkAnswers() {
            var resultArr = [], 
                        flag = false;
            for (i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {

                if (answers[i] == userAnswers[i]) {
                    flag = true;
                }
                else {
                    flag = false;
                }
                resultArr.push(flag);
            }
            return resultArr;
          }

          function roundReloaded(num, dec) {
                var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
                return result;
            }

            function judgeSkills(score) {
                var returnString;
                    if (score==100) returnString = "Einstein!"

                    else if (score>90) returnString = "Uitstekend!"

                    else if (score>70) returnString = "Netjes!"

                    else if (score>50) returnString = "Aanvaardbaar."

                    else if (score>35) returnString = "Nou, dat was slecht."

                    else if (score>20) returnString = "Vreselijk!"

                    else returnString = "Schaam je!"

                return returnString;
            }

              progressKeeper.hide();
              notice.hide();
              $("#main-quiz-holder input:radio").attr("checked", false);

                $('.answers li input').click(function() {
                        $(this).parents('.answers').children('li').removeClass("selected");
                            $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');

                });


              $('.btnStart').click(function(){

                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(500, function(){ progressKeeper.show(); });
                });

                     questionsStatus.text("");
                     return false;

            });   

            $('.btnNext').click(function(){

                    var tempCheck = $(this).parents('.questionContainer').find('input[type=radio]:checked');
                if (tempCheck.length == 0) {
                     notice.fadeIn(300);return false;
                }
                     notice.hide();
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                });
                progress.animate({ width: progress.width() + Math.round(progressWidth/questionLength), }, 500 );
                     return false;
            });         

            $('.btnPrev').click(function(){
                    notice.hide();
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).prev().fadeIn(500)
                });

                progress.animate({ width: progress.width() - Math.round(progressWidth/questionLength), }, 500 );
                     return false;
            });

            $('.btnShowResult').click(function(){

                    var tempCheck = $(this).parents('.questionContainer').find('input[type=radio]:checked');
                if (tempCheck.length == 0) {
                     notice.fadeIn(300);return false;
                }
                var tempArr = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
                for (var i = 0, ii = tempArr.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    userAnswers.push(tempArr[i].getAttribute('data-key'));
                }

                progressKeeper.hide();
                var results = checkAnswers(), 
                              resultSet = '',
                              trueCount = 0,
                              answerKey = ' Juiste antwoorden: <br />',
                              score; 
                for (var i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++){
                    if (results[i] == true) trueCount++;
                    resultSet += '<div class="resultRow"> Vraag #' + (i + 1) + (results[i]== true ? "<div class='correct'><span>Correct</span></div>": "<div class='wrong'><span>Fout</span></div>") + "</div>";

                          answerKey += (i+1) +" : "+ answers[i] +' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;   ';
                }
                     score =  roundReloaded(trueCount / questionLength*100, 2);
                     answerKey = "<div id='answer-key'>" + answerKey + "</div>";

                resultSet = '<h2 class="qTitle">' +judgeSkills(score) + ' Behaalde cijfer '+score+'%</h2>' + resultSet + answerKey;
                $('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();

                     $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                });
                     return false;
            });

})

//antwoorden van quiz
var quiz = { answers: [ 'b', 'c', 'd' ] }
```

I've also looked at youmightnotneedjquery.com but it didn't succeed.

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVymKY

Comment: Didn't you just asked the same question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708097/dynamic-quiz-without-jquery/30709233

Comment: yes the same question, my JS knowledge is very basic :(

Answer (score 0):

May be without animations, it is possible this way, **and it works too**:

```js
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

function calc() {

  var questionsLength = questions.length;
  var score = document.querySelectorAll("#questions input.c:checked").length;
  alert("You have scored " + score + " out of " + questionsLength + ".");
}

var questions = [{
  question: "What is 2*5?",
  choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
  correctAnswer: 2
}, {
  question: "What is 3*6?",
  choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
  correctAnswer: 4
}, {
  question: "What is 8*9?",
  choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, {
  question: "What is 1*7?",
  choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  correctAnswer: 3
}, {
  question: "What is 8*8?",
  choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
  correctAnswer: 4
}];

ready(function () {
  finalHtml = "";
  for (var question in questions) {
    finalHtml += '<li>';
    finalHtml += '<strong>' + questions[question].question + '</strong>';
    finalHtml += '<ul>';
    for (var answer in questions[question].choices)
      finalHtml += '<li><label><input type="radio" name="a-' + question + '" value="' + ((questions[question].correctAnswer == answer) ? '1' : '0') + '" class="' + ((questions[question].correctAnswer == answer) ? 'c' : 'w') + '"> ' + questions[question].choices[answer] + '</label></li>';
    finalHtml += '</ul>';
  }
  document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = finalHtml;
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;}
#questions,
#questions li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
#questions > li {margin: 0 0 10px;}
#questions ul {padding-left: 15px;}
#questions li label {display: block; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<ul id="questions">

</ul>
<button onclick="calc();">Calculate</button>
```

I have given the basic way of implementing or parsing the JSON. You need to figure out the ways next!